# laravel cron job not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

my laravel cron job it does not work automatically. I test it and it seems to work, when I php artisan checkCommissions:check_commissions it runs my task perfectly. so I think the problem is with the command I wrote in cpanel so any help ?

app\Console\Commands\CheckCommissions.php:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\Models\Commission;

class checkCommissions extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'checkCommissions:check_commissions';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Check users counters and give them commissions';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $maxout = Setting::where('name', 'maxout')->first();
        if (!is_null($maxout)) {
            $maxout = $maxout->value;
        }

        if (is_null($maxout) || !is_numeric($maxout) || $maxout < 0) {
            $maxout = 0;
        }

        $commission = Setting::where('name', 'commission')->first();
        if (!is_null($commission)) {
            $commission = $commission->value;
        }

        if (is_null($commission) || !is_numeric($commission) || $commission < 0) {
            $commission = 0;
        }

        $users = User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if ($user->counter_right >= $maxout && $user->counter_left >= $maxout) {
                $num = $maxout;
                $update_counters = User::where('id', $user->id)->update(['counter_left' => 0, 'counter_right' => 0]);
            } else {
                if ($user->counter_right >= $user->counter_left) {
                    $num = $user->counter_left;
                } else {
                    $num = $user->counter_right;
                }

                $update_counters = User::where('id', $user->id)->update(['counter_left' => $user->counter_left - $num, 'counter_right' => $user->counter_right - $num]);
            }

            if($num > 0) {
                $money = $num * ($commission / 2);

                $update_user = User::where('id', $user->id)->update(['money' => $user->money + $money]);

                Commission::insert(['user_id' => $user->id, 'money' => $money]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app\Console\kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\checkCommissions',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();

        $schedule->command('checkCommissions:check_commissions')
                 ->everyMinute(); //
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

and the command in Cpanel:

Minute  Hour    Day Month   Weekday Command Actions

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/gridtumg/public_html/tree/local/artisan checkCommissions:check_commissions >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Can you run  yout `checkCommissions` command without cronjob no error ?

Comment: you should check log file first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes your command is wrong... You want to run a scheduled command within the application console kernel, not scheduling a command execution. Please read the Laravel official documentation about [Task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) (and maybe also the [cron wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)).

You're simply telling to the CPanel crontab to run the command `checkCommissions:check_commissions` everyday at midnight but in your scheduler you want to run that command every minute.

First of all you have to update your cronjob from

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/gridtumg/public_html/tree/local/artisan checkCommissions:check_commissions >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/gridtumg/public_html/tree/local/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

In order to start the scheduler. Then laravel will handle the rest.